# Fix so Let's Encrypt works with www

Tags: apache, ubuntu, lets-encrypt

> Firefox does not trust this site since it uses a certifcate which is not valid for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). Certificate is only valid for example.com.
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

I'm using Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 16, Apache httpd.

How do I add so it also works for **www**?  Some conf in Apache I guess?

Cant find anything about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have installed `certbot` ([docs for your version of Ubuntu and Apache](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-apache)), you should use the `-d` command line switch to list the domains you want the certificate to work for.  [From the docs](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#certbot-command-line-options):

> ```
>  -d DOMAIN, --domains DOMAIN, --domain DOMAIN
>                    Domain names to apply. For multiple domains you can
>                    use multiple -d flags or enter a comma separated list
>                    of domains as a parameter. The first domain provided
>                    will be the subject CN of the certificate, and all
>                    domains will be Subject Alternative Names on the
>                    certificate. The first domain will also be used in
>                    ...
> ```

If you want to do a dry run to test, use `certonly` and `--dry-run` (you'll have to run as `root` or with `sudo`):

```
certbot certonly --dry-run -d www.example.com -d example.com
```

If it looks like everything is OK, actually generate, install and activate the certs with (note this will restart Apache):

```
certbot --apache -d www.example.com -d example.com
```

`certbot` will make the required edits to your Apache config for you.

If you you'd rather make the edits manually, use the `webroot` option.  [The docs for that option](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot) include an example of doing this for multiple domains, including example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).  Removing the other domains from that example to simplify for this case:

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/example -d www.example.com -d example.com
```

You'll need to restart Apache yourself for the new certificates to be used when using this option.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out tonight. I approve if it works.

Comment: @Joe how did it go?

Comment: @Joe, Joe, where are you Joe!? :-)  It seems such a shame to waste half of the bounty ... why?

Comment: Damn. I forgot. Sorry! Worked perfectly.